# Specified Cast not Valid error using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, type-conversion, decimal

Using Nhibernate, Visual Studio 2010, C#.

I am having a problem converting a Decimal? type. The code gives a

> Specified Cast is not valid error

and fails on the .UniqueResult<> line.

Following is my code.

```
private decimal? GetCostValueFromQuery(string query, ItemPriceContext item)
{
    var session = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder()
                                      .CreateSession(typeof(object));
    return session.CreateSQLQuery(string.Format(query, item.ItemCode))
                  .UniqueResult<decimal?>();
}
```

The result of my SQL query is `62.3891005516052`

I suspect the result has a lot of decimal places and hence fails.

Any suggestions how I could Round the result or reduce the result such that it is supported?

Comment: What happens id you use just `<decimal>` Can you query return a NULL result, if it does then maybe you need to use this in your sql `IsNull(<exp>,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever rounding, truncating etc. that you need in the SELECT-part of the SQL query.

But you should also check what the actual return type of the SQL query is. Is it really decimal?

Comment: My sql is returning a decimal (63.31). It may also contain null values hence I used decimal?T he problem lies in the nhibernate query which I am still not able to figure out what. Is there any other way that I can write the same line and get my results.

Comment: @aMazing Like I said, any rounding needs to go in the query itself. Since you are using an SQL query, it needs to go in the SQL query's SELECT part.